# basedir issue, am I reading this right?

Tags: php, plesk, open-basedir

> Warning: touch() [function.touch]: open_basedir restriction in effect.
>   File() is not within the allowed path(s):
>   (/var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/) in
>   /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/Manuals/updater.php on line 5 There
>   was an error loading your Manual, please press the back button and try
>   again.

im trying to figure out why the heck this isn't working - currently, I am using plesk, and it is set to default, which should be working as this is within a subdirectory of the httpdocs...

any ideas?

UPDATER.PHP

```
<?php
//    $URL="manualframe.php";
$URL=$_GET["URL"];
//    header( 'Location: '.$URL.'' ) ;
if (touch($URL)) {
echo 'loading!';
} else {
echo 'There was an error loading your Manual, please press the back button and try again.';
}
echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;URL='.$URL.'">';
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Would the Manuals directory be a symlink to a directory outside the webroot by any chance?

`open_basedir` is also in effect on symlinks within your allowed path(s).

See the [PHP manual on open_basedir](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir) for more information, which states:

> When a script tries to open a file with, for example, fopen() or gzopen(), the location of the file is checked. When the file is outside the specified directory-tree, PHP will refuse to open it. All symbolic links are resolved, so it's not possible to avoid this restriction with a symlink. If the file doesn't exist then the symlink couldn't be resolved and the filename is compared to (a resolved) open_basedir .

Comment: example file is located at site.com/manuals/folder1/sample.pdf
no silly business here :P

Comment: In that case, can you provide us with a code example of updater.php? (Specifically line 5). I misread the errormessage; Manuals/updater.php is within the allowed path, but the file you're trying to `touch` is not, so maybe there's an error in your syntax. (Quite possibly a absolute/relative path issue, e.g. when you try to `touch('/folder1/sample.pdf')` instead of `touch('./folder1/sample.pdf')`

Comment: can't paste code into comments, code added to main post.

notably ive tried '/folder1' './folder1' and even just 'folder1' -nothin.

Comment: onto something currently; it looks like my get variable is not getting sent right for the url, so I guess the idea on the path is right - fixing and seeing if problem is resolved.

Comment: Resolved, get data was being sent with the wrong variable, and the url was missing the variable anyways - fixed both, changed file permissions, problem resolved.
thanks for the lead!

Comment: I tested your code and it seems to work OK (with the urgent remark that directly using unsanitized GET variables is very very dangerous): `http://localhost/test.php?URL=test/test.pdf` does in fact create `test.pdf` *if* the (case sensitive) (sub)directory `test` exists.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like PHP is running in [Safe Mode](http://php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.php). This restriction means you can't read any files outside your web root. That's probably what updater.php is trying to do.

Comment: safe mode is disabled per plesk panel.

all updater.php does is take a file within the manuals subfolder, touch it, and then redirect to it.